# How prevent python write empty line between two lines?

Tags: python, numpy, text

I use python 3.7 in Spyder , anaconda 5.

I have to read from  csv files, each containing lines in one column , and write them to txt files in the same way.

```
import io
import csv
import os
f = io.open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
lines=f.readlines()
np.savetxt(filename+'.txt', lines, delimiter="",newline='\n', fmt="%s")
```

This causes an extra empty line be added between each 2 lines.

in the following image I noticed there is one space at the end of each number, maybe that's the cause :

[image: spyder output]

This is how the output gets and looks like with one line between each 2 lines :

[image: output]

But I don't know how to resolve it. Someone could help ?

Comment: Can you you please show a sample input file (it doesn't need to have more than two lines) and the resulting output file.    It also doesn't need to contain real data (so a line like `0,str,1,0.5` would be fine - and easier to read).  Please post the actual file (as you did with the code), not a screenshot of it.

Comment: As a sidenote, you are not closing your input.  Do not forget to use a f.close() or even better, open the file with a "with" statement.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica The problem is already diagnosed and got 2 answers. uploading a file here is a pain and now will not improve anything.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti You don't need to upload a file here - you need to [edit] the question; open the file in a text editor; copy the two lines; paste the text into the question; place a line containing (at least) three back-ticks above and below the text.

Comment: The problem is in the code, the numbers are not required, reading the code is . did you read the ansewrs ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because

```
f.readlines()
```

includes the `'\n'` at the end of each line, so there's no need to add another newline character when you use `np.savetext`.

To resolve this, simply change your command to

```
np.savetxt(filename+'.txt', lines, delimiter="", newline='', fmt="%s")
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the io.open and the np.savetxt have settings to set the newline character.  They are both applied and result in two "new lines" in between each line.

You can resolve the issue by suppressing the newline character in np.savetxt:

```
np.savetxt(filename+'.txt', lines, delimiter="", newline='', fmt="%s")
```